# Evaluating multiple fn:contains() conditions with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have variable x that i need to check and see does not contain variable y but does contain variable z. 
How would one go about doing that with JSTL? Tried wrapping the statement within another one, but it doesn't seem to register. It only responds to the first evaluation.

```
 <c:if test="${not fn:contains('x', 'y')}">
     <c:if test="${fn:contains('x', 'z')}">

     </c:if>
 </c:if>
```

Would be great if it was possible to do something like:

```
 <c:if test="${fn:contains('x', 'z', not 'y')}">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<c:if test="${not fn:contains(x, y) && fn:contains(x, z)}">

</c:if>
```